Constructing Conditional Phase Shift in Grover's Algorithm and Optimality of Grover's Algorithm for Multiple Solutions
I’m currently working through some questions related to Grover's algorithm and need help with the following:

Conditional Phase Shift Construction using single qubits and two-qubits gate? Also, how can I calculate the total number of gates required for the construction?

Optimality for Multiple Solutions


I've attached an image of the exact questions for reference. Any detailed explanations, insights, or references to relevant materials would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Welcome to QCSE! What things have you tried to solve these? Where are you stuck?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
